# How to typeset a right brace which has exactly the height and depth of contents it braces?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, braces

I want to design a right brace contents whose height and depth are equal to the contents it braces. It is possible to design it using `\left. \right\rbrace`, but I actually want multiple braces to align with each other. Thus, the brace must be placed after the alignment character `&&`. Thus, I need to either measure the content or use `\vphantom`

The solutions below work but they got the one major disadvantage: **they require that I typeset the braced equation twice**. Also, the implementation I am trying to work on using `\saveheightEq` does not align with the solution using `\savebox`. Any possible solutions?

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\heightEq}
\newlength{\depthEq}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\NewDocumentCommand{\basmahspace}{}{\mspace{0.61\thinmuskip}}

\newsavebox\rbracebox

\NewDocumentCommand{\saveheightEq}{m}%
    {%
        \setlength{\heightEq}{\heightof{#1}}%
        \setlength{\depthEq}{\depthof{#1}}%
    }
    
\NewDocumentCommand{\rbraceheightEq}{}%
    {%
        \left. \vphantom{\rule{0pt}{\heightEq}}\vphantom{\rule[-\depthEq]{0pt}{\depthEq}} \right\rbrace%
    }
    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    
    \saveheightEq{$1 - \frac{1 + \ln{\frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}} + 0.72}}{\displaystyle 1 + \frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}}}$}
    
    \savebox\rbracebox{$\left. \vphantom{1 - \frac{1 + \ln{\frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}} + 0.72}}{\displaystyle 1 + \frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}}}} \right\rbrace$}
    
    \begin{alignat*}{6}
        V_{oc} &\approx a \basmahspace V_{t} \basmahspace \ln{\frac{I_{ph}}{I_{0}}}
        && \medspace \bigg\rbrace
        && \text{Increased temperature means increased $I_{0}$}
        \\
        \mathrm{FF}_{i} &= 1 - \frac{1 + \ln{\frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}} + 0.72}}{\displaystyle 1 + \frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}}}
        && \rbraceheightEq
        && \smash{\llap{\vrule width 1pt depth 7em height 2.5em}}\text{Decreased $V_{oc}$ means decreased $\mathrm{FF}$}
        \\
        \mathrm{FF}_{i} &=  1 - \frac{1 + \ln{\frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}} + 0.72}}{\displaystyle 1 + \frac{V_{oc}}{V_{t}}} 
        && \usebox\rbracebox
        && \text{Decreased $V_{oc}$ means decreased $\mathrm{FF}$}
    \end{alignat*}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "a right brace contents whose height and depth are equal to the contents it braces" -- So, are you looking to create an *asymmetric brace, with an upper half that could be either taller or shorter than the lower half? After all, there's nothing to guarantee that the height and depth of the material being embraced are equal.

Comment: @Mico. This is good point, but I want something similar to the result of `\left. \right\rbrace` . The smaller braces must align with bigger ones in `alignat*` environment. without this requirement, the solution is trivial for me